# How to capture Notification icons properties using Microsoft Spy++

Tags: spy++

In System tray when you click the chevron button (Up arrow button) it displays a small window that has a list of notification icons. How to capture these icon properties using Spy++?

Comment: Any update regarding this issue ? did you find a solution ?